# Only use .on() for radio buttons that aren't disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have the following code that run's when a radio button is clicked on. However I am trying to change it so it only runs if the radio button that is being clicked is NOT disabled.

Could anyone help me with this?

```
$('#divName').on('click', 'input[type="radio"]', function(event) { }
```

Comment: disabled elements don't fire events, so you'll have to explain the issue a little better. As a sidenote, you should probably be using the change event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be the use of `:not()`

```
$('#divName').on('click', 'input[type="radio"]:not([disabled])', function(event) { }
```

another would be to exit the function immediately if it is inactive..

```
$('#divName').on('click', 'input[type="radio"]', function(event) { 
    if (this.disabled) return;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`:enabled`](http://api.jquery.com/enabled-selector/) selector:

```
$('#divName').on('click', 'input[type="radio"]:enabled', function(event) { }
```

But depending on what exactly you want to do, you might want to use the [`change`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event instead:

```
$('#divName').on('change', 'input[type="radio"]', function(event) { }
```

Answer (score 1):

how about (not tested):

`$('#divName').on('click', 'input[type="radio"]:enabled', function(event) { }`